# Return Nested List Min/Max Values

Tags: list, nested, max, min

I have searched stackoverflow and found similar request by not able to nail it down. I have a nested list such as

```
[[12, 16], [0, 18], [12, 20], [12, 24], [0, 28], [28, 32], [0, 36], [12, 40], [32, 44], [12, 48]]
```

I am attempting to get the pair of numbers which contain the min value for the first element and the max for second, where both occur in the same pair. In the case above the correct return should be [0,36].  I have been testing with the below statement which I found on stackoverflow. This doesn't seem to give back what I expected, I know I maybe missing something. When I execute the statement, I get  [0, 18], or the first instance of the min value. Other than writing several loops to get the desired result, is there another way? Thanks

```
min(alist, key=lambda item: (item[0], -item[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

After more head scratching was able to understand what needed to be done, thanks to another Python user. 
First sort the first element for min value, then use that sort for the second element. Originally had it done in 2 separate sorts but was shown a one liner.

```
max(v for v in sorted(alist) if v[0] == min(sorted(alist)[0]))
```

This will return the pair (list) that contains the min value for the first element in the list and the max value for the second element in the same list.